# Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at "localhost" after upgrading Angular and Node version

Tags: node.js, angular, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I have an app that was running on `Angular v14` and `Nodejs v14.17.1`. Then I updated it to `Angular v15` and Node 18.15.0 and now `TestCafe` (v2.4.0) fails to load the pages: [Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4DnH.png)
The only thing I can see on the network requests is that the document request returns a 302 that redirects to the about:error page: [network request that fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pgi1.png)

I have tried downgrading to `Node v17` and even 16, also downgrading the `TestCafe` version didn't work.
If I set `experimentalProxyLess` to true then it loads the page but then the authorization header is modified therefore invalid (I have opened an issue for it on `TestCafe`).

Also I'm not considering it as it's experimental.
I have tried setting quarentine mode, the --hostName, nothing of this worked. Also obvious to say, if I open the URL it loads perfectly on the browser outside `TestCafe`

Comment: Now doing more tests. Downgrading to node v14 worked with testcafe 2.2
Using node 18 + testcafe 2.2 didn't work. testcafe 2.4 gives the same result:

Comment: Finally as didn't really find an answer, I downgraded testcafe to the v2.0 and it loaded again the website